# Upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04.1 yesterday and I'm having problems with the keyboard

Tags: upgrade, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

Upgraded yesterday from 20.04 to 22.04. I use three keyboard layouts, ES, EN and CS. With previous releases I've never had a problem, but now Ubuntu seems to refuse to work with the ES layout (which is the one I use the most often). When I switch between tabs, the system seems to "forget" I'm using ES and switches automatically to EN. I tried to solve this by removing the EN layout, but now it either switches to CS or insists on using EN!
Another problem is that the shortcut Ctrl+arrow left/right does not select the word to left/right and Ctrl+arrow up/down does not select the paragraph. Also, the left Ctrl key sometimes doesn't respond for some reason.
PS: I have a regular keyboard with a USB connection, nothing fancy.
**Update:** The problem with the Ctrl+ commands is a bit weirder than I thought at first. If used alone, the commands work fine, but if used in combination with another key, like Shift, only the right side Ctrl key works.

Comment: You may have hit [bug #1956916](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1956916). Try the default shortcut <Super>+Space instead.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson thanks. That seems to have solved the problem with the keyboard layout. Still have the issue with Ctrl+up/down/right/left to select paragraphs/words.